# MySQL LIMIT inside a subquery

Tags: mysql

From an Employee table, I'm trying to get the second highest salary only.
The Employee table has a PK id and a salary column.

```
Select salary as SecondHighestSalary 
From Employee
where id not in (
    Select id from Employee
    Order By salary desc
    limit 1
)
Order By salary desc 
limit 1
```

It's returning: `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: you can find max() and say max() not in (max() id ) to get 2nd highest

Comment: Do you have an example of it?

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 should be something like `select salary as SecondHighestSalary  From Employee where id not in ( Select max(id) from Employee  group by  salary ) Order By salary desc  limit 1 ;`

Comment: [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: @ErgestBasha it does not return anything. `Select max(id) from Employee  group by  salary` return all the Employees